# Call method on other window with JS and don't wait for it to finish

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two browser windows open, let's call them *parent* and *popup*. When the user finishes his work on the *popup* window I want him to click on a button that will call a function on the *parent* window, and close the *popup* window. My problem is that *popup* is being opened until the called function on *parent* won't finish. This is annoying because the function on *parent* opens up `alert`, `confirm` etc boxes, and the *popup* window is still in the foreground. So I want to run the function call and window closing simultaneously.

Here is the code:

```
window.opener.addStationery(id, name, qty);
this.close();
```

Comment: What if you invert those lines ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown Well I did not assume that will work, but It did. This solved the probem, thanks!

Comment: Great! Posted as an answer if you like to accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invert those lines:

```
this.close();
window.opener.addStationery(id, name, qty);
```

Even closing the window the scope is still on.

Answer (score 0):

Close the Popup in the parent function in the parent page before doing other operations.